# Access corporate git (under vpn) from private laptop through corporate laptop(proxy)

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, git

I have corporate crappy slow macbook, which configured to work with VPN. 
I have my personal macbook pro 16. They are both in my home LAN. I want to work on my personal macbook Pro through slow macbook;s vpn. So corporate's git should be accessible from my private laptop.
How to configure this?

Comment: Are you authorized to use your personal PC?  Most companies either provide the necessary information to do this themselves or are against downloading company source code to an employee’s personal machine.  In either case you should be contacting your corporate IT department for assistance as they have the necessary information to help you

Comment: well, I haven't signed any document restricted me to do so. Our it dept is always busy and probably they don't know or they will say look confluence for documentation and there are no such cases solved yet, and them very lazy to do it from scratch

Comment: Here is the thing.  It doesn't appear you even know the IP address of your VPN server.  You indicate the corporate laptop is using a laptop, but the title of your question, mentions both a VPN and a proxy.  Your IT department will be able to supply you with this information.

Comment: Configure your corporate macbook to forward IP connections ("share the internet"), configure your personal macbook to use your corporate macbook as gateway. Bang, your personal macbook is also in the VPN (with all the risks for the corporate network that this entails).

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.